# Set Minecraft folder from command line (with 2017 launcher)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Previously, this was possible using

```
set APPDATA=%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Games\minecraft-test
```

then

```
path\to\minecraft.exe
```

This does not seem possible using the new 2017 launcher: MinecraftLauncher.exe appears to ignore the `APPDATA` path change.  Is it possible to change `APPDATA` temporarily just for MinecraftLauncher.exe?

---

Some explanation

I want to keep completely separate installations so I can use various different selections of mods. My previous method had been working fine until the new launcher installed today.

Comment: Recently minecraft added an inbuilt java . This may have something to do with it.

Comment: I don't think so. It's happened on the launcher that's only just been released and Minecraft has had its own Java for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this *is* possible from the command line. Instead of setting the `APPDATA` variable, the launcher itself can be made to use another folder.

The command goes like this:

```
minecraftLauncher.exe --workDir %HOMEPATH%\Documents\Games\minecraft-test
```

That should give you an isolated Minecraft install that you can then install Forge on top of and any mods you like.